# Targets for FSharp project with MonoFramework?

Tags: f#, mono, xamarin

I've found solution to get C# / F# on travis: [How do I use Travis-CI with C# or F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751772/how-do-i-use-travis-ci-with-c-sharp-or-f)

except I get 3.2.4 version

I checked archive and found fsharpc there but can't find `Microsoft.FSharp.Targets` or something alike...

So... my Visual Studio F# project contains:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets" />
```

And sure it will not work there... I was trying several ways including downloading `Microsoft.FSharp.Targets` from F# opensource github but then it was trying to use fsc instead fsharpc, that was a bit strange for me...

So in nutshell how should I make my `fsproj` file to be look like to make it work on `MonoFramework` provided by `Xamarin` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do in xamarin?  Also, have you installed the language bindings for F#?

Comment: @mydogisbox all I have is from here: http://download.mono-project.com/archive/${MONO_VER}/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-${MONO_VER}.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg where version is 3.2.4

Comment: There are details on setting up monodevelop with F# support here: http://fsharp.org/use/mac/  It doesn't sound like you've installed the F# plugin.

Comment: there is no mono-develop and I hope that I don't need it to build F# project.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Monodevelop is basically the same thing as Xamarin Studio.  The plugin idea still applies.

Comment: @mydogisbox I don't use monodevelp or Xamarin Studio or even any graphical environment there.

Comment: Ah, now I follow.  Sorry, a bit slow.  Looks like this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856141/build-an-f-project-file-on-os-x-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Visual Studio 2013 myself, but have helped another OSS project who did, get running on mono.

The current VS2013 `fsproj` has a conditional import for VS2012 (v11) for fsharp targets.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

by adding an `Or $(OS) != 'Windows_NT'` this will work with xbuild of mono 3.2.4.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0' Or $(OS) != 'Windows_NT'">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```